# SOAP-WS security header authentication

Tags: java, soap, soapui, ws-security, soapheader

I have developed a webservices using spring+ XSD+ Payload. I have a requirement of authenticating the request header with username and password coming in SOAP request header which i achieved with SOAPUI

I m able to generate the below header in the request

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:jaxb="http://jaxb.miws.sg.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
   <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-C3092BFBAE5B212E93144378035575013">
   <wsse:Username>User</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">test</wsse:Password>
   <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">CT1Fyo/g2WMaadE52bsnkg==           </wsse:Nonce>
   <wsu:Created>2015-10-02T10:05:55.750Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Now i want to validate the header elements for userName and Password.

Ex:

Case 1:
   userName=User and Password=test //Authentication passed and give response Success

Case 2:
   userName=User1 and Password=test1 //Authentication failed and give response Failure

Please help me to provide the suitable samples to achieve same.

Answer (score 0):

Handlers in SOAP webservices (similar to Interceptors/Filters) can be used for the authentication purpose on the server side and then chaining the request further. 
Please have a look at SOAPHandler to parse the header information from the payload and authenticating the username/password.
[SOAP Handler at Server Side](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to do that:

1. Implement a `SOAPHandler` class by writing a custom `handleMessage` method.
2. Within the `handleMessage` method, evaluate the context's `MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY`. If it is false (meaning it is an inbound message), then write code that introspects the `context.getMessage()`. There you can evaluate the MIME headers, the security headers & tokens and the body, to determine if you need to reject the authentication credential. If you do, return `false` at the end of the method.
3. Add the `SoapHander` you created to the service's Handler chain.

**Example of a SOAPHandler:**

```
public class MyCustomSoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
  public Set<QName> getHeaders()
  {
    return Collections.emptySet();
  }

  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext)
  {
     Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)
         messageContext.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

     if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
         //This is for handling messages going out of the conduit
     } else {
         //Here is where you want to authenticate
     }

     return true; //return false if do not want to proceed to the next handler in the chain
  }

  public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext messageContext)
  {
    return true;
  }
   public void close(MessageContext messageContext)
  {
}
```

**Here a starter template for your SOAPHandler that you need to add to your Service's handlerChain:**

```
@WebService(name = "Handler", targetNamespace = "http://example.org")
@HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml")
public class HandlerWS
{
  @Resource
  WebServiceContext ctx;
  @WebMethod()
  public String getProperty(String propertyName)
  {
    return (String) ctx.getMessageContext().get(propertyName);
  }
}
```

**You'll also need to add the `handler-chain.xml` to your classpath:**

examples.webservices.handler.Handler1
    
  
  
    
      examples.webservices.handler.Handler2

For a complete guide, see [Oracle's guide to creating `SOAPHandlers`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html)